# how to restart apache / tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache2, restart

I need to restart an Apache2 server running on Ubuntu. It has several tomcat applications.

Do I just have to go to the init.d/apache2 directory and type “./apache2 restart”?  But, I’m not sure if I then have to separately restart all the tomcat applications – or vice-versa?

If it helps, the apache2 server is configured with “sites-available” and “sites-enabled”. These are mostly tomcat applications, such as “myWebApp1”, "myWebApp2", etc, which have separate startup scripts of their own. When I deploy a new war file, I manually run the startup scripts and don't have to restart apache2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This two server are independant. 
You could restart Apache and keeping Tomcat running.

systemctl restart apache2  (with right acces) (or /etc/init.d/apache2 restart)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a script that first restart Apache2 and then call your startup scripts